What's wrong with my Pachyphytum leaves?
I have two Pachyphytums, which have been doing fine (although no massive growth) for a couple of years. I never watered them that much, but over the past few months, I've watered them a little more. As a result of this, they have both grown quite a bit.
However, I noticed this morning that they both have a couple of sick looking leaves at the bottom. I know this is something can happen to any plant, but as the rest of the plants seem to be doing well, I wondered if there was anything specific I was doing wrong, or could do better...

Anyone able to advise? Thanks

Is what they are planted in a mixture of bark and sphagnum moss?

@kevinskio I think it's pure sphagnum, can't see evidence of anything else in there. They've been in that since I got them.

There is a mismatch between the soil that succulents do best in and the sphagnum moss they are in.  Sphagnum is great at retaining moisture and providing a soil with lots of air pockets.  It is perfect for plants that need moisture all the time without the soil being waterlogged. Succulents benefit from a free draining soil and being watered when they are growing which can be seasonal in the spring depending on where the plant's light comes from.
I suggest that your plants have been slightly overwatered and this is the cause of the problem.  This could be resolved by:

watering less (after all it seems to have worked for a while)
providing a lot more direct sunlight
repotting in a free draining soil mix: something like a tropical soil mix of peat, perlite with added perlite.  Surprisingly most sand is not a great additive as it compacts quickly.


Thanks for the reply. Not sure what counts as less watering, but initially I hardly watered them at all, and my "increased" watering is only about once a month. Is that too much? They are sitting on a windowsill that gets a lot of light, and as much direct sunshine as anything can get in England . I have some sphagnum peat and perlite, would that be OK? If so, what percentage mix do you recommend? Thanks again

@AvrohomYisroel I suggest that spaghnum moss is the problem and using a pre mixed soil for cacti and succulents or tropical mix with more perlite is the way to go

Thanks for the advice. I was hoping to be able to use the peat and perlite I already have, rather than having to buy pre-mix for the small amount I'd need!
